# Neo4J Batch Inserter is slow with big ids

Tags: neo4j

I'm working on an RDF files importer but I have a problem, my data files have duplicate nodes. For this reason, I use a big ids to insert the nodes using batch inserter but the proccess is slow. I have seen this  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26627394/neo4j-batchimporter-is-slow-with-big-ids) when Michael recommends to use a index but the process remains slow.

Another option would be to merge duplicate nodes but I think there is no automatic option to do so in Neo4J. Am I wrong?

Could anyone help me? :)

Thanks!

Comment: Please post sample data along with the code you're using to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no duplicate handling in the CSV batch importer yet (it's planned for the next version), as it is non-trivial and memory expensive.

Best to de-duplicate on your side.

Don't use externally supplied id's as node-id's that can get large from the beginning that just doesn't work. Use an efficient map (like trove) to keep the mapping between your key and the node-id.

I usually use a two-pass and an array for it then sort the array, array index becomes node-id and after sorting you can do another pass that nulls-out duplicate entries

Answer (score 0):

Perfect :) The data would have the following structure:

> chembl_activity:CHEMBL_ACT_102540 bao:BAO_0000208 bao:BAO_0002146 .
>
> chembl_document:CHEMBL1129248 cco:hasActivity
>   chembl_activity:CHEMBL_ACT_102551 .
>
> chembl_activity:CHEMBL_ACT_102540 cco:hasDocument
>   chembl_document:CHEMBL1129248 .

Each line corresponds with a relationship between two nodes and we could see that the node **chembl_activity:CHEMBL_ACT_102540** is duplicated.

I wanted to save as id the hashcode of the node name but that hashcode is a very large number that slows the process. So I could check for ids to only create the relationship and not the nodes.

Thanks for all! :)